# Vim bind compile key depending on document type

Tags: vim, latex, compile, c

Is there a way to bind a key by document type?

For example, if the document is a .tex file, I want f5 to call `PdfLatex`, but it is a .c file, I want it to call `make`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<buffer>` option to the `map` command to specify that a mapping be used only in the current buffer, then apply that mapping only in buffers of a particular file type using an autocommand, like this.

```
au FileType tex map <buffer> <F5> :PdfLatex<CR>
au FileType c   map <buffer> <F5> :make<CR>
```

For more, see

```
:help map-<buffer>
:help autocmd.txt
```